# Get surrogate pairs from an emoji

Tags: ios, swift

What I'm trying to do is check if an emoji can be rendered on the iOS device by using this:

```
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName("AppleColorEmoji", 12, nil)
    var code_point: [UniChar] = [0xD83D, 0xDE0D]
    var glyphs: [CGGlyph] = [0, 0]
    let has_glyph = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &code_point, &glyphs, 2)

    if has_glyph == false {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
```

It takes two code points and checks if the emoji can be rendered. Now what I'm having trouble with is how do I get the surrogate pairs *directly* from an emoji. I've Googled around and I can't seem to find any way to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the UTF-16 representation of a character:

```
let emoji = ""
let utf16codepoints = Array(emoji.utf16)
```

`utf16codepoints` is an `[UInt16]` array, and `UniChar` is a type alias for `UInt16`, so this array can be used directly in `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters()` to check if a font has a glyph
for this character (now updated for Swift 3/4):

```
let font = CTFontCreateWithName("AppleColorEmoji" as CFString, 12, nil)
var glyphs: [CGGlyph] = [0, 0]
let has_glyph = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, utf16codepoints, &glyphs, utf16codepoints.count)
print(has_glyph)
// true
```

Hex dump the array to verify that it is the same as the 
`code_point` array in your question:

```
print(utf16codepoints.map { String($0, radix: 16)} )
// ["d83d", "de0d"]

print(utf16codepoints == [0xD83D, 0xDE0D])
// true
```

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the quotes and just get something like `[d83d, de0d]`?

Comment: @DIllionDaniels: `utf16codepoints` is an array of integers, and you can directly use it with CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters (see updated answer). The print statement was just meant as a demonstration and prints the integers in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for Obj-C implementation:

```
- (BOOL)isEmojiSupported:(NSString*)emoji
{
    NSUInteger length = [emoji length];

    unichar characters[length + 1];
    [emoji getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
    characters[length] = 0x0; 

    CGGlyph glyphs[length];     
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("AppleColorEmoji"), 12, NULL);
    BOOL ret = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, characters, glyphs, emoji.length);
    CFRelease(ctFont);

    return ret;
}
```